# H2O-R: Apply custom library function on each row of H2OFrame

Tags: r, h2o

After importing a relatively big table from MySQL into H2O on my machine, I tried to run a hashing algorithm ([**murmurhash** from the R digest package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/digest/index.html)) on one of its columns and save it back to H2O. As I found out, using `as.data.frame` on a H2OFrame object is not always advised: originally my H2OFrame is ~43k rows large, but the coerced DataFrame contains usually only ~30k rows for some reason (the same goes for using `base::apply`/`base::sapply`/etc on the H2OFrame).

I found out there is an `apply` function used for H2OFrames as well, but as I see, it can only be used with built-in R functions.

So, for example my code would look like this:

```
data[, "subject"] <- h2o::apply(data[, "subject"], 2, function(x) 
                                digest(x, algo = "murmur32"))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in .process.stmnt(stmnt, formalz, envs) : 
  Don't know what to do with statement: digest
```

I understand the fact that only the predefined functions from the Java backend can be used to manipulate H2O data, but is there perhaps another way to use the digest package from the client side without converting the data to DataFrame? I was thinking that in the worst case, I will have to use the R-MySQL driver to load the data first, manipulate it as a DataFrame and then upload it to the H2O cloud. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Do you want to hash the entire column into a single value?  That's currently what your code does (if it were a regular R data.frame) since you have set `margin = 2` (columns) instead of `margin = 1` (rows).  Since you are trying to replace the `data[,"subject"]` column with the results, my guess is that you are actually trying to apply the hash function to each row.  I have an answer for you, but I want to make sure I understand what you are trying to do first.

Comment: Yes, just to make sure, I want to apply the hash function to each row seperately. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way H2O works, it cannot support arbitrary user-defined functions applied to H2OFrames the way that you can apply any function to a regular R data.frame.  We already use the Murmur hash function in the H2O backend, so I have added a [JIRA ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4196) to expose it to the H2O R and Python APIs.  What I would recommend in the meantime is to copy just the single column of interest from the H2O cluster into R, apply the `digest` function and then update the H2OFrame with the result.

The following code will pull the `"subject"` column into R as a 1-column data.frame.  You can then use the base R `apply` function to apply the murmur hash to every row, and lastly you can copy the resulting 1-column data.frame back into the `"subject"` column in your original H2OFrame, called `data`.

```
sub <- as.data.frame(data[, "subject"])
subhash <- apply(sub, 1, digest, algo = "murmur32")
data[, "subject"] <- as.h2o(subhash)
```

Since you only have 43k rows, I would expect that you'd still be able to do this with no issues on even a mediocre laptop since you are only copying a single column from the H2O cluster to R memory (rather than the entire data frame).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and for adding the JIRA ticket! It would be a great addition I think. I tried pulling the "subject" column into a data.frame, but the problem is, even this dataframe becomes smaller than the original H2O frame, for some reason.

> h2o.nrow(data)
[1] 43594

> nrow(sub)
[1] 32367

And when I try to copy it back to H2O, I get an error message: "Requires same count of rows in the number-list (43594) as in the source (43823)"
(I don't really understand what is 43823 there) Maybe there is something I'm missing, some parameters of H2O has not been set perhaps?

Comment: That sounds like a bug with `as.data.frame()`.  Do you have the data.table package installed?  If you do, you should try using and then not using data.table on the backend.  Try again first using `options("h2o.use.data.table"=TRUE)` and then `options("h2o.use.data.table"=FALSE)` and let me know if one of those two gives the correct number of rows.

Comment: Great, it finally worked with options("h2o.use.data.table"=TRUE) (I tested it with FALSE as well, and the problem of less rows in the dataframe reappeared). I knew about this package, but I didn't know that h2o had such an option. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Hadron It's a new option meant to speed up the `as.h2o()` and `as.data.frame()` functions.  I'm glad to hear that data.table is doing the right thing.  It sounds like the bug appears when using the default `as.data.frame()` backend.  If there is any way that you can upload your dataset to JIRA, it would be great to look into this bug further. https://0xdata.atlassian.net/projects/PUBDEV